# exact total memory usage in linux that equals to system monitor

Tags: c, linux

By getting Memtotal and Memfree values from "/proc/meminfo" and subtracting them we must get the Used Memory in Linux. Most of threads and web pages that I have visited have guided through this approach to compute the Total Memory Usage in Linux. But by implementing this method, I get different results with GNOME System Monitor! My result is greater than that (approximately double). So what is the method that GNOME System Monitor uses?

Comment: GNOME is open-source. Go see how they calculate it!

Comment: Not sure about GNOME system monitor, but have written some lines about top,htop,free,ps [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65852/28489) and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58541/28489) that might help ...

Comment: Thanks @Sukminder. I saw your recommended pages. The exact memory usage formula is : used memory=(MemTotal-MemFree)-(Buffers+Cached);

Comment: @user2949310: Yes, thought so. In other words same as `free`. Added a more detailed answer and included source references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*GNOME system monitor*](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gnome-system-monitor/) uses [`libgtop`](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/libgtop/) to retrieve memory information for various platforms. For Linux it uses `sysdeps/linux/mem.c`<sup>[2](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/libgtop/)</sup> where the routine is as follows:

Strings like *"MemTotal"* are headings in `/proc/meminfo`.

```
…    
    buf->total  = get_scaled(buffer, "MemTotal:");
    buf->free   = get_scaled(buffer, "MemFree:");
    buf->used   = buf->total - buf->free;
    buf->shared = 0;
    buf->buffer = get_scaled(buffer, "Buffers:");
    buf->cached = get_scaled(buffer, "Cached:");

    buf->user = buf->total - buf->free - buf->cached - buf->buffer;
```

The memory reported in the application is `buf->user`. More precisely in `src/load-graph.cpp`<sup>[1](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gnome-system-monitor/)</sup> by:

```
mempercent  = (float)mem.user  / (float)mem.total;
set_memory_label_and_picker(GTK_LABEL(graph->labels.memory),
                            GSM_COLOR_BUTTON(graph->mem_color_picker),
                            mem.user, mem.total, mempercent);
```